# I keep getting a "missing operator" error on Access and SQL. Query worked before I tried joining table to itself

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT ap.ID, ap.[Adjustment Name], ap.[Adjustment Name Description], ap.[2nd Item Number], [ap].Description, ap.[Unit of Measure], ap.[Effective Date], ap.[Expired Date], MAX( ap.[Factor Value Numeric] ) , ap.[Prc Cls], ap.[Prc Cls Description], ap.[Address Number], ap.[Sales Detail Value 01], ap.[Currency Code], c.[Customer Pricing Rule], c.[Alpha Name]

FROM [Adv Price Query Export] ap 

INNER JOIN ( SELECT [Adjustment Name], [2nd Item Number], MAX([Effective Date]), [Factor Value Numeric], [Sales Detail Value 01] 
FROM [Adv Price Query Export] ) s ON ((s.[Adjustment Name] = ap.[Adjustment Name]) AND (s.[Effective Date] = ap.[Effective Date]) AND (s.[Sales Detail Value 01] = ap.[Sales Detail Value 01]))

INNER JOIN Customer  c ON (ap.[Adjustment Name] = c.[Adjustment Schedule])

WHERE ( ap.[2nd Item Number] = "18500" OR ap.[2nd Item Number] = "185047" OR ap.[2nd Item Number] = "18550" OR ap.[2nd Item Number] = "26004" OR ap.[2nd Item Number] = "55010" )
GROUP BY  ap.[Sales Detail Value 01]
```

Comment: I think it is because `MAX([Effective Date])` in your subquery doesn't have an alias. You should also follow the general `group by` rule: All attributes in the `select` should be either in the `group by` or in an aggregate function (`max`, `count` etc).

Comment: I was led to believe that aliases got distributed in subqueries, as in "INNER JOIN (SELECT SUBQUERY) alias ON...", is this wrong? (I hate SQL on Access, btw)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the error is but you can re-write your query like below

```
SELECT ap.ID, 
ap.[Adjustment Name], 
ap.[Adjustment Name Description], 
ap.[2nd Item Number], 
[ap].Description, 
ap.[Unit of Measure], 
ap.[Effective Date], 
ap.[Expired Date], 
MAX( ap.[Factor Value Numeric] ) , 
ap.[Prc Cls], 
ap.[Prc Cls Description], 
ap.[Address Number], 
ap.[Sales Detail Value 01], 
ap.[Currency Code], 
c.[Customer Pricing Rule], 
c.[Alpha Name]

FROM [Adv Price Query Export] ap 

INNER JOIN ( SELECT [Adjustment Name], 
[2nd Item Number], 
MAX([Effective Date]), 
[Factor Value Numeric], 
[Sales Detail Value 01] 
FROM [Adv Price Query Export] ) s 
ON s.[Adjustment Name] = ap.[Adjustment Name]
 AND s.[Effective Date] = ap.[Effective Date]
AND s.[Sales Detail Value 01] = ap.[Sales Detail Value 01]

INNER JOIN Customer  c ON ap.[Adjustment Name] = c.[Adjustment Schedule]

WHERE ap.[2nd Item Number] IN ("18500", "185047", "18550", "26004", "55010" )
GROUP BY  ap.[Sales Detail Value 01]
```